# Set env Variables in react project

Tags: reactjs, environment

Someone please help me with below

```
i have installed npm i env-cmd
i have 2 files in the src folder
.env.development 
REACT_APP_URL="DEVELOPMENT"
.env.production
REACT_APP_NAME="PRODUCTION" 

package.json file
"start": "env-cmd .env.development react-scripts start",
"build": "env-cmd .env.production react-scripts build",
```

But i get nothing while do this in app.jsx

### {process.env.REACT_APP_NAME}

i also dont get any error in cmd

Comment: try to re-check the name of the variable you are using. whether the name is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1):

well you have `REACT_APP_URL` in dev but you're trying to access `REACT_APP_NAME` so of course it doesn't work

change this: `REACT_APP_URL="DEVELOPMENT"` to `REACT_APP_NAME="DEVELOPMENT` and it should work